# ASP.NET Custom Profile Error

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database, asp.net-profiles

I have an issue with an ASP.NET profile implementation. This is my profile code:

```
public class UserProfile: ProfileBase
{
    public static void Get()
    {
        return (UserProfile)Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName);   
    }
    public static void Get(string username)
    {
        return (UserProfile)Create(username);
    }

    //this property works
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get{ return base.GetProperty("FirstName") as String; }
        set{ base.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value); }
    }

    //this property works
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string LastName
    {
        get{ return base.GetProperty("LastName") as String; }
        set{ base.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value); }
    }

    //this property throws "The settings property 'Email' was not found." error.
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get{ return base.GetProperty("Email") as String; }
        set{ base.SetPropertyValue("Email", value); }
    }

    //this property throws "The settings property 'Telephone' was not found." error.
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get{ return base.GetProperty("Telephone") as String; }
        set{ base.SetPropertyValue("Telephone", value); }
    }
}
```

My web config looks like this:

```
<profile inherits="UserProfile" defaultProvider="SqlProfileProvider">
    <providers>
        <add 
            name="SqlProfileProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
            connectionStringName="Profile" 
            applicationName="Management" />
    </providers>
</profile>
```

For some reason when the code executes and I retrieve or update a profile for the current user it blows up. However, what is more curious is that the FirstName and LastName properties work fine. The errors only occur when accessing/updating the the EmailAddress and TelephoneNumber properties.

If I add the `<properties>` section in the web.config profile section for the FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, and TelephoneNumber properties a different type of error shows up - "Property is already defined" or something along the lines...

Any ideas on how to fix this? Also you need to know that the back-end for the profile system is SQL Azure, while the front-end is an Azure WCF service.

Thanks,

```
<bleepzter/>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are matching your field names with the property names?  Email != EmailAddress && Telephone != TelephoneNumber

Comment: Thanks. Please write this as an actual answer as this was the answer. Who would've ever thought that the field names have to match? I mean the ProfileBase implements the properties as a dictionary/hashtable. I thought it's similar to the StateBag used for Session/ViewState etc.. Absolutely nowhere have I found a post that states the internal property keys have to match! Moreso, the implementation of UPM Membership/Role Providers for Commerce Server has different keys than their property names.

Comment: @bleeptzer: Aaron won't get your message unless you address the message to him (as I've addressed you in this comment).

Comment: @Aaron D: Thanks. Please write this as an actual answer as this was the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are matching your field names with the property names? Email != EmailAddress && Telephone != TelephoneNumber

Comment: Thank you sir ! I was struggling with this problem for two days ! But why should property name be exactly the same with base string ?